# Should I use EXT methods/constants in OpenGL <2.0

Tags: opengl, version

I'm coding a 3D game for PC with pretty low minimum system requirements in mind (anything better than Pentium II 400MHz and GeForce3 should be ok). I read in docs that this or that function started as EXT and ended up being included into OpenGL core in version 1.3 or 1.4.

In dglOpenGL headers there are both glBindFramebuffer and glBindFramebufferEXT methods with GL_FRAMEBUFFER and GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT constants. My question is - which version should I be using EXT or noEXT?

Is it possible that some Intel built-in GPU whose drivers meet only version 1.3 will accept glMethodExt and will crash upon the same glMethod (without EXT in the end)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use what is available on that implementation. A core feature will be denoted by a version number. If you're expecting core FBO support, you would need to get a version 3.0 or greater.

Extension support is denoted by the extension string. You should check for available extensions at startup and you should not use any extension that isn't there.

Now, there are some ARB extensions which are "core extensions". This means that the #defines and functions do not have the ARB suffix. So ARB_framebuffer object is an extension, but it defines `glBindFramebuffer`, without a suffix. This means that you can check for version 3.0 *or* the extension, and in either case, you use the same functions and #defines.

Core extensions almost always mean the exact same thing as the core equivalent. Non-core extensions can have changes. For example, ARB_geometry_shader4 is not a core extension, and the core geometry shader functionality from 3.2 is *vastly* different in terms of specification and API.

You generally should have some minimum OpenGL version that you accept, and then run different codepaths based on the presence of higher GL versions and/or extensions.

Comment: The thing is - I need <2.0 versions support. So what you saying I need to manually check if glMethod or glMethodExt exists? Is there a rule?

Comment: @Krom: You don't check for functions; you check for extensions and version numbers.